# How to write selected columns to Kafka topic?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1v with java 1.8.
and kafka versions spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11_2.4.3 and kafka-clients_0.10.0.0

```
StreamingQuery queryComapanyRecords = 
                 comapanyRecords
                 .writeStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",KAFKA_BROKER)
                .option("topic", "in_topic") 
                .option("auto.create.topics.enable", "false")
                .option("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
                .option("value.serializer", "com.spgmi.ca.prescore.serde.MessageRecordSerDe")
                .option("checkpointLocation", "/app/chkpnt/" )
                .outputMode("append")
                .start();



queryLinkingMessageRecords.awaitTermination();
```

**Giving error :**

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Required attribute 'value' not found;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$$anonfun$6.apply(KafkaWriter.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$$anonfun$6.apply(KafkaWriter.scala:71)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
```

I tried to fix as below, but unable to send the value i.e. which is a java bean in my case.

```
  StreamingQuery queryComapanyRecords = 
                     comapanyRecords.selectExpr("CAST(company_id AS STRING) AS key", "to_json(struct(\"company_id\",\"fiscal_year\",\"fiscal_quarter\")) AS value")
                    .writeStream()
                    .format("kafka")
                    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",KAFKA_BROKER)
                    .option("topic", "in_topic")
                    .start();
```

> So is there anyway in java how to handle/send this value( i.e. Java
>   bean as record) ??.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Kafka data source](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) requires a specific schema for reading (*loading*) and writing (*saving*) datasets.

Quoting the [official documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#creating-a-kafka-source-for-batch-queries) (highlighting the most important field / column):

> Each row in the source has the following schema:
>
> ...
>
> **value** binary
>
> ...

In other words, you have Kafka records in the `value` column when reading from a Kafka topic and you have to make your data to save to a Kafka topic available in the `value` column as well.

In other words, whatever is or is going to be in Kafka is in the `value` column. The `value` column is where you "store" business records (the data).

On to your question:

> How to write selected columns to Kafka topic?

You should "pack" the selected columns together so they can all together be part of the `value` column. `to_json` standard function is a good fit so the selected columns are going to be a JSON message.

### Example

Let me give you an example.

Don't forget to start a Spark application or `spark-shell` with the Kafka data source. Mind the versions of Scala (`2.11` or `2.12`) and Spark (e.g. `2.4.4`).

```
spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.4
```

Let's start by creating a sample dataset. Any multiple-field dataset would work.

```
val ns = Seq((0, "zero")).toDF("id", "name")
scala> ns.show
+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
|  0|zero|
+---+----+
```

If we tried to write the dataset to a Kafka topic, it would error out due to `value` column missing. That's what you faced initially.

```
scala> ns.write.format("kafka").option("topic", "in_topic").save
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Required attribute 'value' not found;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$.$anonfun$validateQuery$6(KafkaWriter.scala:71)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:138)
  ...
```

You have to come up with a way to "pack" multiple fields (columns) together and make it available as `value` column. `struct` and `to_json` standard functions will do it.

```
val vs = ns.withColumn("value", to_json(struct("id", "name")))
scala> vs.show(truncate = false)
+---+----+----------------------+
|id |name|value                 |
+---+----+----------------------+
|0  |zero|{"id":0,"name":"zero"}|
+---+----+----------------------+
```

Saving to a Kafka topic should now be a breeze.

```
vs.write.format("kafka").option("topic", "in_topic").save
```